# ¿Como resuelvo este problema relacional de un modelo de negocio para un laboratorio de análisis clínico?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Tengo una **duda** con respecto para resolver este problema relacional:

Tengo una catalogo de una lista de varios tipos de **estudios**, éste contiene los atributos: nombre del estudio, precio, tiempo de realización de estudio y referencias(un dato numérico de referencia de lo normal que debe ser, dependiendo el análisis).Y con estos mismos datos tengo que hacer un **grupo de estudios o paquetes** que debe tener otros precios y tiempos de realización, esos paquetes el administrador se encargará de hacerlos. Entonces una vez que el **paciente** desee un estudio o paquete de estudio ¿Cómo podría relacionarlo con la tabla **pedidos**?

Espero que me haya dado a entender. gracias de antemano

El diagrama que pienso es más o menos esta así (incompleto).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pareciese una pregunta basada en opiniones, checa [ask], por que de ser así pudiera terminar cerrada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si me permites ir un paso más atrás de tu modelo relacional y partir del ER, necesitas una relación entre las entidades `pedidos` y `paquetes` que indique cuántos paquetes incluye cada pedido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como entiendo que un pedido puede incluir varios paquetes y un paquete lo pueden incluir en diferentes pedidos, la cardinalidad es N:N, no podemos propagar el campo o flag que los vincula y, por tanto, no podemos prescindir de esa tabla. Probablemente por eso te costaba ver cómo resolverlo. La próxima vez que dudes, recurre al modelo Entidad-Relación, seguro que lo verás todo mucho más claro. Al fin y al cabo es donde empieza todo...

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo mucho para darme una mejor idea y poder concluir el diseño y modelado. La próxima vez empezare desde este punto.

Answer (score 0):

Podría realizarse con una flag que indique si el pedido va referenciado a un paquete o a un estudio individual. Regularmente cada paquete imagino lo vas a controlar con un Id, indicando su costo (como una apreciación general) y podrías añadir una tabla mas donde se contenga el detalle de cada paquete con sus costos y características especiales.

Con base en lo anterior, en la tabla pedidos indicas si el cliente esta adquiriendo un estudio individual o un paquete, con los estudios individuales, según dices, ya se encuentran funcionando, entonces con esta forma ya tendrías la relación para el detalle de los paquetes que van a ofrecer.

Espero te sirva. Saludos!!

Comment: Disculpa tienes algún ejemplo con flag?

Comment: Estuve buscando acerca de flag y no he encontrado, agradecería un ejemplo, gracias